# Best way to search into MySQL with artificial intelligence like google

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I'm building a web crawler which collects crawled results into MySQL table.

There are Five Main Columns: `URL, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, KEYWORDS, BODY`.

Currently I'm using `FULLTEXT` search function of MySQL as follows:

```
SELECT URL,title, description, MATCH (description, keywords, title, URL) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) 
AS score FROM record
WHERE MATCH (description, keywords, title, URL) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) order by score desc;";
```

But it is not giving me good results. Consider the following image.
[image]

Here, the facebook is at 23rd position on searching `"Facebook"`.**(?)**

Can i prioritize the search based upon the coloumn name? For example, I want the query to give maximum priority to `URL`, then `description`, then `title`, `keywords`.. and finally `body`.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Based on the criteria you require, you won't get what you want from a query.  You'll want to process the results of the query with some php to give them priority.

Comment: Yes. your point is 100% true. But if i go on processing each and every record from table, the system will go damn slow. The table has millions of rows.

Comment: You wouldn't return *all rows* and then process... run the query like you have it, *then* process.

Comment: @cale_b Yeah.. I didn't gave it a thought. That was helpful. Thank you.

Comment: First of all you need to consider your MySQL version and storage engine. You also will want to look into the nuances of SQL storage engines for full text search. A good place to start is here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/03/04/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-2-the-queries/. To really make any progress on this you will at least need to understand MyISAM vs InnoDB for FTS. As to prioritizing, yes you can, but there is no one right way to going about doing it. This is kind of a semester long grad course (or two. Or five). Easy answers will have many flaws.

Comment: @evanv Thank you the link. It is really interesting. Well if there is some good grad course, I have no issues going for that too. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT URL,title, description, MATCH (description, keywords, title, URL) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) AS score FROM record WHERE URL LIKE '%$keyword%' OR MATCH (description, keywords, title, URL) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) order by score desc;";
```

Just use LIKE operator for URL matching. See above code. Thank U!

Answer (score -1):

Look at something like SoundEx:

See: http://www.madirish.net/?article=85

Additionally could you not considering doing the weighting yourself:  (I don't have MySQL local, so sorry for the semi-pseudocode)

```
SELECT 
    URL
    ,title
    , description
    , MATCH (URL) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) AS urlscore 
    , MATCH (description) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) AS descscore 
    , MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) AS titlescore 
    , MATCH (body) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) AS bodyscore 

    ,((MATCH (URL) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode))*4) 
    + ((MATCH (description) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode))*3) 
    + ((MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode))*2) 
    + ((MATCH (body) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode))*1)  AS weightedscore
FROM    
    record
WHERE 
    MATCH (description, keywords, title, URL) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode) 
order by 
    ((MATCH (URL) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode))*4) 
    + ((MATCH (description) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode))*3) 
    + ((MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode))*2) 
    + ((MATCH (body) AGAINST ('$keyword' in boolean mode))*1)  desc;
```

Comment: The article tile is "Using Soundex with MySQL" with very specific articles.  What more do you need - cael?

Comment: Thank you for the link. It would be helpful. +1

Comment: Per the stackoverflow guidelines, link-only answers are not good answers.  From [how do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) **Provide context for links** - *Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Comment: @AnthonyHorne You need the answer to be _here_, not on another site. Summarise the main technical points here, and provide the link as a backup. Not the other way round

Comment: @Clivecale A search on Google/Bing for "SoundEx" yields 1.4M/1.5M results of which top10 over 40% relate directly to SQL. If this will assist the person asking the question, to get closer to his/her answer, I am not sure I see the problem. Are we not trying to help each other? If in a year from now the link is no longer here, a quick search will find updated articles both at stackexchange AND elsewhere to help. There are articles as recent as last month ON microsoft related to changes on SoundEx. Why would I want to point people to old and irrelevant articles. I must not be getting the point..

Comment: Cipherux:  Sorry for the semi-rant.